# json with asp.net mvc not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I used firebug in Mozilla code below and it simply does not run. Any suggestions?

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); //only executes this line, then exit
$.ajax({
    url : "/Home/LoadMap",
    dataType: "json",
    type:"post",
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {

            .........

        });

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you handle the error property in your request. Does that get hit?

Comment: not appear any error, only executes the first line and does not execute the rest

Comment: What about Firebug's network tab? Does it register a call to /Home/LoadMap?

Comment: `{cache: false}` setting affects only HEAD and GET requests and can be ommited here

Comment: What I am saying is if you add: error: alert('Error!'); for instance nothing happens?

Comment: I've tried removing the '{cache: false}' @Dima, but did not work

Comment: on the local machine is running normally, but when I put in IIS is not running

Comment: Não acontece nada quando coloca o 'alert('Error!')' @MikeCheel

Comment: Can you give me an example @ChrisHardie

Comment: You'll need to monitor the network request the browser is making for `/Home/LoadMap` either with the 'net' tab in Firebug or a tool like Fiddler. The goal here is to determine what the request and response headers look like. This will indicate whether the error is client-side script or on the server.